# Wait for AJAX request ( React, Redux)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, redux

Need display data after AJAX call will be done.

My Reducer:

```
import { INCOME_PROFILE } from '../actionTypes'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

const initialUserState = [];
const profileReducer = function(state = initialUserState, action) {
   //console.log('actiondata in reducer:' + action.data + action.type);

  switch(action.type) {

    case 'INCOME_PROFILE_IS_LOADING': 
     return Object.assign({}, state, {  hh: action.hasFetched });

  case 'INCOME_PROFILE': 
         return Object.assign({}, state, { course_list: action.data, hh: action.hasFetched });

  default: 

  return state;
  }
}
export default profileReducer
```

My action creator:

```
export function GET_ITEM_REQUEST() {
  return {
    type: INCOME_PROFILE_IS_LOADING,
    hasFetched: false,
  }
}



function receiveData(json) {
    return{

        type: INCOME_PROFILE,
        data: json,
        hasFetched: true
    }
};

export function IncomeProfileList () {

    return dispatch => {

        return (

            axios.post(Api.getURI("profile"),{}, {
      headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
     }).then(function (response) {


                //console.log(response.data);
                dispatch(receiveData(response.data.body));

            })
        .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
            )
    }
}
```

My component:

```
class IncomeProfile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.IncomeListProfile();
      }

render() {
console.log(this.props.isloading);

if (this.props.isloading) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  return {
      IncomeListProfile: () => dispatch(IncomeProfileList())
      }
  }

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  //var mystore = state.toJS()
  var mystore = state.getIn(['incomeProfileList'])['course_list'];
  var mystored = state.getIn(['incomeProfileList']);
  console.log(mystored.hh);
  var copy = Object.assign({}, mystore);
  return {
    items: copy.course_list,
    isloading: mystored.hh
        };

}
```

I need next: While response not finish, I no need to display data. Condition if not works now

console.log at first time get undefined - think must be false, but it not state false. and second time it's getting true.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need property 'isLoading' - just handle 2 cases in which you have your data and you haven't. Put this condition in render() function, because the component is going to refresh after passing data through the reducer. Syntax will be something like this in your case:

```
  render() {
    if(!this.props.items) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Display your data!</div>
      ); 
    }
  }
```